# Hiding spring form input tag when field is empty

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp

I have a Spring form input tag in my code that looks like this

```
<form:input path="${field}" id="${id}" placeholder='${placeholder}' type="${type}" cssClass='${inputCssClass} ${alert}' cssStyle="${cssStyle}"
    title="${tooltipText}" data-validation="${validation}"
    data-validation-length="${validationLength}"
    data-validation-format="${validationFormat}"
    data-validation-confirm="${validationConfirm}"
    data-validation-regexp="${validationRegexp}"
    data-validation-allowing="${validationAllowing}"
    data-password-validation="${dataPasswordValidation}"
    data-validation-error-msg="${dataValidationErrorMsg}"
    data-validation-error-msg-required="${dataValidationErrorMsgRequired}"
    data-validation-error-msg-length="${dataValidationErrorMsgLength}"
    data-validation-error-msg-number="${dataValidationErrorMsgNumber}"
    data-validation-error-msg-date="${dataValidationErrorMsgDate}"
    data-validation-error-msg-email="${dataValidationErrorMsgEmail}"
    data-validation-error-msg-alphanumeric="${dataValidationErrorMsgAlphanumeric}"
    data-validation-error-msg-confirmation="${dataValidationErrorMsgConfirm}"
    data-validation-require-leading-zero="${dataLeadingZero}"
    data-validation-optional="${dataOptional}"
    autocomplete="${autocomplete}"
    readonly="${isReadonly}"
/>
```

I should hide this entire tag when the field is empty. I run through [Spring's documentation for such tag](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form-tld.html#spring-form.tld.input) but I had no luck in finding a suitable solution. I tried using `cssErrorClass` attribute to set a class with hidden display but it doesn't apply that class on an empty field.

Comment: why not use JSTL and `<c:if>` tag? I'd do in this way: `<c:if test="${not empty model.path}"> YOUR INPUT CODE HERE </c:if>`

Comment: Unfortunately the input tags should be rendered but hidden, in such a way that can be easily shown on javascript events

Comment: Well i'd do in this way `<c:choose><c:when test="${not empty model.path}"> <c:set var="hiddenClass" value=""/> </c:when><c:otherwise><c:set var="hiddenClass" value="hidden"/></c:otherwise></c:choose>` Then in your input you can use the JSTL var `${hiddenClass}`

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer. That looks interesting as a solution. Excuse my dumb question, i'm not really into Java, but my model.path is always empty even for fields that have a value. Should I change that part to something else? I put the <c:choose> before the <form:input> and the result on the page is https://i.imgur.com/plUqZBN.png (no fields shown, model.path always empty

Comment: I guess your inputs are inside a form where you use a modelAttribute. What is your modelAttribute name? model should be the name of your modelAttribute. May you post the form code too?

Comment: Sure, the form is like this https://pastebin.com/GzHjbELx. I tried putting something like modelAttribute="regform" in the <form:form> tag and using regform.path in the formInput but I can't get it to work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Is `<form:form>` a spring taglib? In this case you are using `commandName` object; in your case you are using `commandName=userProfileForm` so you should use `userProfileForm` as name. Did you try to do something lie this `userProfileForm.field`?

Comment: That's it! I'm able to access single attributes by using for example `${userProfileForm.firstName}`. Unfortunately using `${userProfileForm.field}` throws a `PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'field' not found` exception. I also tried with `${userProfileForm.${field}}` but still it doesn't work (exception). Any way to read for each input its right property?

Comment: Yes you shoule do several check one for each field. Otherwise you can make your command more complex and do the logic in the controller side

Comment: I'm totally unqualified to edit the controller as I only do frontend. I think I will loop through every field to check for their emptyness, ugly but still better than letting javascript handle it after page load. Thanks for everything!!